# Dynamically create key in JavaScript object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to dynamically create a key in a `JavaScript` object with a `jQuery` selector:

```
{
  $("form").children("input[type=hidden]").attr("name"): $("form").children("input[type=hidden]").val()
}
```

This is breaking though. Is it possible to dynamically create a key this way?

Comment: Do you only have one input element, or should it work for multiple values?

Comment: Only a single hidden input.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend having a `input[type=hidden]` selector; if you add another hidden input value, it might break your code. It would be better if you named it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it in two statements :

```
var obj = {};
obj[$("form").children("input[type=hidden]").attr("name")]
    = $("form").children("input[type=hidden]").val();
```

I'd personally write it like this to avoid recreating the jQuery set:

```
var obj = {}, $obj = $("form").children("input[type=hidden]");
obj[$obj.attr("name")] = $obj.val();
```

Note also that this only makes sense if the jQuery set contains exactly one element.

Answer (score 1):

You can also make it work with multiple fields at once:

```
var obj = {};
$('form > input[type="hidden"]').each(function (i, el) {
    obj[el.name] = el.value;
});
```

Another more fancy version in case if you have only one hidden field:

```
var obj = $('form > input[type="hidden"]').serializeArray()[0];
```

Comment: Not bad but OP commented to say he only has one field.

Comment: Oh, right, didn't see that. Anyway, maybe someone will need it.

Comment: Yes, you should keep your answer, this might be useful ;)

Comment: But note that your selector isn't equivalent to what OP gave. You probably should add `>` (supposing OP had a good reason to use `children`).